# phonegap fileTransfer upload get fileuploadoption values

Tags: php, cordova

I am following the file upload documentation and is successful in uploading the picture with this code

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

But how do I access the fileuploadoptions that is sent to the server? I am using php code to upload the picture to a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those come through as regular post fields, so `$_POST['value1']` and `$_POST['value2']`